# How to compile a 3rd C++ party source code as shared library

Tags: c++, windows, shared-libraries

I downloaded a third party source code, [EDFlib](http://www.teuniz.net/edflib/), and would like to compile it (using Visual Studio) into a shared library with all symbols exported.

Header file looks like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...
long long edftell(int handle, int edfsignal);
...


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When I compile the header and source file in Visual Studio, no .lib is generated (probably meaning that no symbol is exported).

Is it possible to compile this into a shared library with all symbols exported **without modifying the library header file at all**? This would make it easy to switch to a newer version when the 3rd party team releases one.

Note:

If I had created the library myself, I would have done this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifdef EDFLIB_EXPORTS
        #define EDFLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define EDFLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else 
    #define EDFLIB_API
#endif

long long EDFLIB_API edftell(int handle, int edfsignal);
```

It would be possible to modify the library header file with those export flags but I don't want to modify it, I'd like to find an alternative.

Comment: You are missing some Windows (or Win32) tag. You won't have any issues on Linux.

Comment: Honestly, the `edflib.h` have lots of comments, and not many functions (less than 30). Adding `EDFLIB_API` at several places in that header file is probably the most simple & pragmatic solution, and you might even make a pull request on github for that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You are right for the WIN32 flag (I updated my post). I agree it would be easy for this lib, but I already had the same problem in the past for bigger libs and now I'd like to find an alternative to modifying the source code....As there are some `extern C` tag, I was wondering if there was any way to make all this be actually exported...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for a larger library would be to automatize this task, but that is probably not as easy as it looks (non POD data in C++, `enum`s, ...)

If you compile with some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. on Linux), you might customize it with my [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) tool, perhaps by making it generate some `ed` script to patch the header. It is not an easy task (probably a few weeks of work), and I would recommend going this way only for a quite large library (e.g. of a million lines of C++), and even in such a case, it might not worth the pain to partly automatize the thing....

For your EDFlib the simplest way is to patch their [edflib.h](https://github.com/Teuniz/EDFlib/blob/master/edflib.h) file (you'll probably need to add `EDFLIB_API` at about 30 declarations) and make a pull request on github.

The real issue is that Windows and POSIX (at least Linux and most Unix like AIX, Solaris, HPUX) have *incompatible* views regarding the role of the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) and the nature of [dynamic libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (and of symbols inside them). Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book explains that in details. This is also why I am skeptical about a fully automated approach (the developer is the only one knowing what exactly should be exported, and how to do that; so for your library, you'll need to annotate your declarations for export; at last, making a C-compatible API for a C++ library often requires some redesign and code refactoring).

NB. GCC MELT is a plugin for GCC, and GCC does not allow plugins on Windows (but does allow them on Linux), precisely because of the issue you are encountering: decorating every exported function with `__declspec(dllexport)` is too painful.

Comment: Does the linker create a DLL from the source? If it does, check its content for exported functions (with Dependency Walker or similar tool). -- it was meant to the original question --